# Sqlserver insert into from user

Tags: sql, sql-server

i started writing on ms sqlserver 2014 yesterday, started from access and im having a syntax difference problem.
this is my current code

```
INSERT INTO costumer ( costumer_name, costumer_address,costumer_date_of_birth, costumer_phone )
VALUES ([costumer name], [costumer address], [costumer dob], [costumer number]);
```

i want the user to enter each of the costumer name,address,dob,number.
i changed my code to sqlserver and it changed to this

```
INSERT INTO costumer ( costumer_name, costumer_address, costumer_date_of_birth, costumer_phone )
VALUES ('costumer name','costumer address','costumer dob','costumer number');
```

but it didn't work because that's surely a wrong syntax...

Comment: What is the error you having when running the sql?

Comment: Could you show the schema for the table? maybe because the data type

Comment: It's because the VALUES are strings.

Comment: @Chuck 
'code'
create table costumer

(
costumer_id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
costumer_name varchar(25),
costumer_address varchar(30),
costumer_date_of_birth datetime,
costumer_phone int,
);
i know i have data type problem, i want user to be able to fill the tables...how is that possible ?

Comment: Then @Kramb is correct. You can't insert a string value into a datetime or int column.

Comment: @RidaHelbawi the costumer number is an integer, you can use string instead

Comment: @JodyT i know i have a datatype problem, but what im asking for is how would i let the user decide what to fill in the table ?

Comment: @RidaHelbawi A Webform, MVC application, Excel. That's a pretty loaded question...

Comment: oh thought its as simple as access

Comment: Well your users wouldn't add data to the Access DB from the backend. You build a frontend in Access. You would do the same for SQL.

Comment: @Kramb oh thank you then... i still have so much to learn...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert into a `datetime` and `int` datatypes column a `string`, your syntax has to look:

```
INSERT INTO costumer ( costumer_name, costumer_address, costumer_date_of_birth, costumer_phone )
VALUES ('costumer name','costumer address','2016-03-09',1);
```

As asked in your comments, how a user puts data into SQL? Kindly, any front-end user don't have any access to the back-end SQL server or any database behind you have to use either a web or desktop application that allows the user to enter and receive information from your database.

A better understanding how to use databases you can look over [here](https://wikis.engrade.com/access)

Comment: but i dont want to be the one filling the table, i want the user to fill the tables instead...

Comment: im writting with sql server

Comment: A user don't have access directly to sql server, you have to use some application to it, either of a web form or desktop application

Comment: oh thanks for your answer.. that explains so much ! still alot to learn